# Why am I getting jest errors when creating this table?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1068

I'm trying to use primary key for more than one place; however, in my table I get jest error about multiple primary key defined-get.

Below is my code:

```sql
create table orders (
 order_id int AUTO_INCREMENT, 
 ordered_from int, 
 PRIMARY KEY (order_id), 
 FOREIGN KEY (ordered_from) REFERENCES restaurants(restaurants_id), 
 delivery_man int, 
 PRIMARY KEY (order_id), 
 FOREIGN KEY (delivery_man) REFERENCES delivers(deliver_id), 
 user_num int, 
 PRIMARY KEY (order_id), 
 FOREIGN KEY (user_num) REFERENCES users(user_id)
);
```

Please help me out. What would be the right syntax?

I'm trying to use the `id` from all of my tables in one table of the order.

In `orders` table, Im trying to put the user, delivery man, and the restaurant.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> create table orders (
>  order_id int AUTO_INCREMENT, 
>  ordered_from int, 
>  PRIMARY KEY (order_id), 
>  FOREIGN KEY (ordered_from) REFERENCES restaurants(restaurants_id), 
>  delivery_man int, 
>  PRIMARY KEY (order_id), 
>  FOREIGN KEY (delivery_man) REFERENCES delivers(deliver_id), 
>  user_num int, 
>  PRIMARY KEY (order_id), 
>  FOREIGN KEY (user_num) REFERENCES users(user_id)
> )
> ```

A `FOREIGN KEY` is a field (or collection of fields) in one table, that refers to the `PRIMARY KEY` in another table. The *restaurants_id*, *deliver_id* and *user_id* needs to be primary key in the *restaurants*, *delivers* and *users* tables respectively.

Change the above declaration syntax as mentioned below

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
 order_id int AUTO_INCREMENT, 
 ordered_from int,
 delivery_man int, 
 user_num int, 
 PRIMARY KEY (order_id), 
 FOREIGN KEY (ordered_from) REFERENCES restaurants(restaurants_id), 
 FOREIGN KEY (delivery_man) REFERENCES delivers(deliver_id), 
 FOREIGN KEY (user_num) REFERENCES users(user_id)
);
```